# Hashtbl.create complexity

Tags: hashtable, ocaml, complexity-theory

I read somewhere saying the complexity of Hashtbl.create is O(nlogn).

I thought it strange since Hashtbl are implemented as arrays and Array.create has complexity O(n). So I looked into the source code:

```
let rec power_2_above x n =
    if x >= n then x
    else if x * 2 > Sys.max_array_length then x
    else power_2_above (x * 2) n

let create ?(random = !randomized) initial_size =
    let s = power_2_above 16 initial_size in
    let seed = if random then Random.State.bits (Lazy.force prng) else 0 in
    { initial_size = s; size = 0; seed = seed; data = Array.make s Empty }
```

Looks to me first it finds the smallest 2-power above the *initial_size* then making an array out of it. This does not sound like O(n logn)... I'm thinking something like O(2**(logn +1)).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your actual question?  Can it only be answered "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: "I'm thinking something like O(2**(logn +1))" that's exactly the same as O(n).

Comment: "I read somewhere saying the complexity of Hashtbl.create is O(nlogn)." Where did you read this? Also, is it possible you confused Hashtbl with some other data structure (e.g. Set or Map)?

Comment: Actual question: what's the complexity of Hashtbl.create?

Comment: @newacct: yes it's O(n), I was trying to express exactly the notion of "smallest 2-power larger than n". Read it in the book <OCaml for scientists>, and no I didn't confuse it with Set/Map. It was Hashtbl. (since Map would be easy to understand -- it's implemented as balanced trees)

Comment: it's a bit complicated a question you ask, because it depends on the number of elements. When that number becomes too high wrt the number of bucket lists, the hashtable is rebuilt with a larger array (see the `resize` function in the code).

Comment: "smallest 2-power larger than n" is O(log n), and hashtbl creation is O(n), but you don't multiply the two, you add them, O(n + log n) which is just O(n).

Answer (score 1):

What does `n` mean in your example? In the case of an array, we say that its creation is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements of the array. In the case of a hashtable, there is an underlying array initialized of size `O(n)`, but `n` here is not related to the (future) number of elements of the hash table, only to the initial size parameter.

You may always pass size `1` or any constant of your liking, and the hash table will have to be resized more often, which is a costly but amortized operation: a ridiculously small initial size will only affect the constant multiplicative factor of your running time, not its algorithm complexity. A ridiculously large initial size will cause a huge constant overhead in time and memory (and possibly fail on a 32bits architecture, or if you don't have enough memory).